# JavaFX Bindings.createBooleanBinding does not work with ToggleGroup?

Tags: binding, javafx-8

I have two code snippets which should do the same:

1st one

```
toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("test1");
});
```

2nd one:

```
Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> new Predicate<Toggle>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Toggle toggle) {
        System.out.println("test 2");
        return toggle != null;
    }
}.test(toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().getValue()
), toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty());
```

The first code example works. The second one does not. It seems like the createBooleanBinding method does not react on property changes while the addListener method does.

Can anyone help or explain this behaviour?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I have a factory method to bind the predicates to the binding.. But this method does not work with the factory method because the listener is not called